# Python 3.8.10 on local server but 3.8.12 on Azure server when I print "sys.version", would that cause problem?

Tags: python-3.x, django, azure-web-app-service, python-3.8

I have 2 questions.

I have depoloyed Django project in Azure Web App service.

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello Nicholai! This is just for testing!" + platform.platform() + "\n " + sys.version)
```

With the code above, it shows Python version is 3.8.12

In my local Windows Subsystem for Linux it is Python version 3.8.10.

**Would it cause problems to use different Python releases (3.8.10 vs 3.8.12) between Azure and local PC?**

I didn't found out how to change Azure server Python to 3.8.10.
There are different guides on how to install 3.8.12 on Linux but it may not be optimal and I don't want to deal with that (as I'm don't have much clue about installing Python manually).

**My 2nd question is:** when I run Kudus bash and type `python3 --version` it shows 3.5.3 but in the "ENVIRONMENT" page and when I run the code above (with sys.version) it prints it's 3.8.12 (I did choose 3.8 when setting up the web app service). **Which one is the true Python version for the Azure server?**

Comment: Likely not, but this is _the_ main reason to work with container technology (like docker): to ensure that you are running the software in exactly the same environment.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Do you know if Microsoft Azure provides any guide / setup such container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To Change the version in Azure Linux Web App

In Azure Linux Web App service run the below  `Powershell` Command

```xml
az webapp config set --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --linux-fx-version "PYTHON|3.8.12"
```

[image]

**To get the current version,**
Run the below command

```xml
az webapp config show --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --query linuxFxVersion
```

[image]

- The version changes can also be seen in Azure Linux App Service Environment.

[image]